# "Too early to say" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

Having some trouble in finding a good equivalent of the English pattern: "too early to say/judge". The most naïve literal translation might be: *"id nimis praematurum ad dictum/ut dicatur"*, or better: *"id praematurius quam ut dicatur/aestimetur"* but I suspect there are better more idiomatic options. It is tempting to use the supine *dictu* somehow, but its usage is quite limited and all in it seems not a good fit — or not?

Answer (score 5):

This can be approached with a possessive genitive with an infinitive, a structure that came up in [a recent question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/17270/79).
Allen and Greenough, [in §343.c](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/genitive), give the following example:

> **Sapientis est pauca loquī**
> *It is wise (the part of a wise man) to say little.*
> (Not **sapiēns** [n.] **est pauca loquī**)

We can take a similar approach to your phrase:
It's not too early to say, but it is of a hasty person to say.
Based on this idea, I'd suggest:

> *Festinantis est iudicare.*

This strikes me as pithy, clear, and idiomatic.
You can of course adjust the tone by choosing different adjectives and verbs.
You should consider switching *festinans* to *praeceps*, for example.
In this use I would slightly prefer *iudicare* over *dicere*, but either one works.
Or you can turn things around:
It is of a patient person not to judge yet.

Comment: Your suggestion reads to me as a timeless statement, whereas the English idiom is used as an answer to particular questions.

Comment: @Kingshorsey True, my suggestion is indeed timeless in nature. But I think if I make a formally timeless statement like this in a context, its implications on the present situation are pretty clear. Quoting an old wisdom is not exactly equivalent to a direct comment on a particular matter, but an option worth considering.

Answer (score 5):

I would say:

> *Nimis cito loqui*

This is based on a comment made by Pliny the Younger ([Epistulae III, 20](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0139%3Abook%3D3%3Aletter%3D20%3Asection%3D9)):

> *Sed nimis cito de futuris*
>
> But it is too soon [to speak] of what is to come

Comment: I disagree that the missing word in Pliny is loqui. I would instead say that it's just the finite form loquor/dico (= 'But I'm speaking too soon about what happened only later' = 'But I'm getting ahead of myself'), which is often ellipsed in such cases (cf., e.g., Quid plura?). Such an epexegetic infinitive with nimis cito strikes me as a grecism/poetic, at best – which is not to say that it isn't possible; but I'd want to see some example that includes an explicit infinitive.

Comment: @cnread - Of course I never claimed that *loqui* was the missing infinitive in Pliny's quote — that was my own addition. However, I thought it was justified considering that Cicero similarly used the combintation *sero* + the infinitive: "Atque idem ego, cum iam opes omnis et suas et populi Romani Pompeius ad Caesarem detulisset **seroque ea sentire** coepisset"

Comment: Surely the infinitive in the Cicero is dependent on coepisset, not sero?

Comment: I would phrase this: Nimis cito loquerer  ("I would be speaking too soon," with it understood, "if I were answering your question")

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is:

> *praecedant omnia verba/dicta rem/res.*
>
> All (any) words [if they were spoken] would anticipate the facts/reality/outcome.

This is inspired by a combination of...

- [Seneca], *Hercules Oetaeus* 517:

  > *'infide vector' inquit, 'immixti licet
  >
  > Ganges et Hister vallibus iunctis eant,
  >
  > vincemus ambos, consequar telo fugam.'
  >
  > **praecessit arcus verba**; tum longum ferens
  >
  > harundo vulnus tenuit haerentem fugam
  >
  > mortemque fixit. ...*
  >
  > 'O treacherous ferryman,' he said, 'even if Ganges and Hister should flow in joined riverbeds, I shall overcome both of then and catch up with your flight with my dart.' **His bow anticipated his words**; then the reed, bearing a wound from afar, checked his flight so that it made no further progress, and implanted death.
- Caesar, *Bellum civile* 3.36.1:

  > *nam plerumque in novitate **fama <rem> antecedit**.*
  >
  > For it's generally the case that, in novel situations, rumors outpace facts.

  (Although the *rem* is an emendation, all editors appear to accept it.)

The problem that I see with this is that the subjunctive is a bit too open to other interpretations (e.g., jussive). A less ambiguous alternative would be something like this:

> *ne praecedant verba rem/res.*
>
> Let not words anticipate the facts/reality/outcome.

Answer (score 2):

How about *iam nescimus*? I'm also thinking about *res praematura est*, or working the adverb *praemature* into the sentence.