# In regards to "Est" and "Errare humanum est"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, infinitive

I am new to Latin and very rough because I am teaching it to myself after so many years. I was working on a sentence that I thought was simple enough but became confused. The translation of "Errare humanum est" is "to err is human", a translation that I did not really like. I wanted the Latin to translate into English in a way that I spoke and made more sense to me.

I attempted to change the Latin so that the English translation would be "To err is to be human" but ran into some problems and need clarification and help. The Latin that I wrote came out as "Errare est esse hominem/homines" and I have a few questions about that.

- Can 'est' and 'esse' even be used in the same sentence in this instance?
- Also, can I just get rid of 'est' if 'errare' is already the verb in the sentence?
- And is the word human plural or singular in the Latin form because it is referring to the whole human species?

I know the plural in English is 'humans' but I did not know if that was a similar case in Latin. Is anything I am saying making any sense at all because I don't know Latin.

Comment: "I wanted the Latin to translate into English in a way that I spoke" – how about *errare humanum est*, 'making mistakes is human'?

Answer (score 4):

Latin and English have different selections of structures and idioms available, so translating too literally is often a bad idea — or even outright impossible.

I think your suggestion *errare est esse hominem/homines* is grammatical (there are [subtleties with the subject of the infinitive *esse*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1877/79) but the accusative seems to be correct), but it does sound unidiomatic to me.
You are forcing an English structure on Latin.

I would suggest taking a look at the inventory of structures available in Latin itself instead.
One such option is to use the genitive and say *Hominum errare est* meaning things like "it is in human nature to err" or "it is the humans' tragic weakness to err" or "it is characteristic of humans to err" or similar.
If you want to go from the plural "humans" to the singular "a human", just switch *hominum* to *hominis*.
See [Allen and Greenough, §343.c](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/genitive) and my answer to [a question on such uses of genitives](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/17270/79) for details.

---

Do you interpret the word "human" in "to err is human" to be a noun or an adjective?
I think it is intended to be an adjective here, although the word is perhaps more commonly used as a noun in English.
This might be a source of some confusion.
I think "To err is to be human" is a fine translation of *Errare humanum est*.

Answer (score 0):

You've stumbled onto some deep subtleties.

The first thing to understand is that *errare* functions as a noun in "Errare humanum est". *Errare* is an infinitive: it denotes the action of erring but it does not make a claim about the action of erring. A finite verb asserts a claim, like *errat* in "Qui rogat non errat" (He who asks does not err). A noun denotes something so we can talk about it; a (finite) verb says something about it.

It's the same in English. In "To err is human", *to err* functions as a noun: it's the subject of the sentence. The verb is *is.* And the verb links the subject with the adjective *human.*

So, you can't get rid of *est*; *errare* is not the verb.

If you want a literal translation of "To err is to be human", you could say:

> Errare est esse humanum.

"Errare est esse homines" would mean "To err is to be people"—not what you mean.

In English, *human* functions as both noun and adjective. In Latin, *homo* is the noun and *humanus* is the adjective. In "Errare est humanum", *humanum* is in the neuter to agree with *errare*; infinitives have neuter gender. *Humanum* is also in the nominative because it agrees with *errare,* which is nominative because it's the subject of the sentence. And *humanum* is singular because *errare* is singular. *Errare* really is a noun!

---

If this doesn't sink in right away, give yourself time—and more examples. While nothing here is complicated, it's subtle, and it's something that people normally pick up intuitively and never develop words to describe. Notice how in English we have no trouble understanding "To be is to be perceived" or "seeing is believing" but most people lack words to explain the grammar. We effortlessly grasp that "to be" is what the first sentence is *about,* even though we call "to be" a verb. Most people would say that *seeing* is a verb, but it also functions as a noun. It's the same in Latin:

> Esse est percipi.
>
> Videre est credere.

Comment: In the light of [this older question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1877/79) and its answer, I'm not sure if you should have *errare est esse humanum* instead.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I was wondering about that myself, and looked it up to check my intuition that the subject complement of _esse_ should be nominative since it doesn't modify anything in the sentence. I understand it to be like _vis beatus esse_ mentioned [here](https://latindiscussion.org/threads/accusative-and-infinitive-clauses.33681/) (not covered by Asteroides, I think). I could be wrong, of course. I was hoping to avoid this much trickier subtlety, but I suppose there's no escape!

Comment: I don't think there's an escape from the subtlety unless you recast the sentence somehow, and I keep being confused by this. My intuition agrees with yours and wants to go with the nominative, but the answer by Asteroides proves my intuition wrong in many cases.

Comment: The accusative is necessary unless the infinitive is complementary.

Comment: @Kingshorsey Thanks. Can you point me to a good resource to read further about this? I had thought that the n.c.i. in complements like _vis beatus esse_ was explained by some deeper principle, perhaps the infinitive's lack of its own grammatical subject. That principle would then carry over to a situation like the present one, where _esse_ is a subject complement.

Comment: @BenKovitz: my interpretation of *vis beatus esse* is that *beatus* agrees there with the understood nominative subject of the entire clause (*tu*). But there is no understood nominative subject of *esse* in a sentence like "Errare est esse humanu[s/m]". I would put it as "errare est esse humanum."

Comment: Regarding my answer there, I think "Hercules fortis esse vult" is the same kind of sentence as "vis beatus esse".

Comment: @BenKovitz this is not as thorough as I’d like, but it is addressed in A&G 452.3, note 2. The example there is non esse cupidum pecunia est.

Comment: @Kingshorsey Asteroides Thanks! I will check out the A&G section when I have time. For now, I will defer to your well-studied advice and change it to _humanum._ The OP has plenty of easier topics to be confused about already. :)

Comment: @BenKovitz In *Vis beatus esse* the infinitive is not the subject; that is a very different case. Another example is *didici industrius esse*. But it is not an NcI, because an NcI is, by definition, a passive construction of a verb that in the active would take an AcI.

Comment: @Kingshorsey AGS 452.3, note 2 seems to settle it! I am still puzzled by the principle and will probably ask a new question about it.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Mihi nunc vidētur mē nōminātīvum cum īnfīnītīvō numquam intellēxisse.

Comment: @BenKovitz the principle seems to be that the subject of an infinitive is an accusative. Therefore, the predicate of an infinitive is an accusative. The only exception is the complementary infinitive, in which case the finite verb and infinitive work together like a single finite linking verb.